# onActivityResult is not displaying image

Tags: android, android-bitmap

So, I want to take a picture and display it on the screen. I can press the button and take a picture but it isn't showing it on the `ImageView`. I can't find the solution with searching `onActivityresult`.

What I have now:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnCamera = findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        // Open camera and take picture
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("Data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: "data" should be lower case.

Comment: do you give proper permission in your app?

Comment: It is working now, data is now lowercase and yes I gave permission. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Instead of:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("Data");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK )
    {
        Uri imgUri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imgUri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);}}
```